# Javascript Toggleable Function

Tags: javascript

I am currently making a function where if you click this `div` element, an `svg` element will show up inside the `div` by using the `innerHTML` but when you click on it again, that element will change to another svg, so basically, I want the function itself to be toggleable. How can I make it work?

```js
var daynightSVG = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" height="512"><path d="M24,13V11H18.928a6.927,6.927,0,0,0-.438-1.621l4.392-2.557L21.876,5.094,17.482,7.652a7.077,7.077,0,0,0-1.142-1.14l2.55-4.385L17.162,1.121l-2.55,4.385A6.91,6.91,0,0,0,13,5.072V0H11V5.072A6.908,6.908,0,0,0,9.4,5.5L6.854,1.121,5.126,2.127,7.671,6.5A7.046,7.046,0,0,0,6.524,7.646L2.14,5.094,1.134,6.822,5.513,9.371A6.9,6.9,0,0,0,5.072,11H0v2H5.072a6.948,6.948,0,0,0,.438,1.622L1.141,17.165l1.006,1.729,4.372-2.546a7.028,7.028,0,0,0,1.13,1.131L5.1,21.865l1.729,1.006,2.548-4.382A6.912,6.912,0,0,0,11,18.928V24h2V18.928a6.918,6.918,0,0,0,1.638-.445l2.552,4.388,1.728-1.006L16.362,17.47a7.06,7.06,0,0,0,1.125-1.128l4.383,2.552,1-1.729-4.382-2.551A6.928,6.928,0,0,0,18.928,13Zm-7-1c-.21,6.608-9.791,6.606-10,0C7.21,5.392,16.791,5.394,17,12Z"/></svg>`;
var modeToggle = document.getElementById("modeToggle");
modeToggle.innerHTML = daynightSVG;

modeToggle.onclick = () => {
  daynightSVG = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" height="512"><path d="M14,24A12.013,12.013,0,0,1,2,12C1.847,3.044,12.031-2.985,19.791,1.509l1.553.862-1.543.88c-6.7,3.688-6.21,13.87.8,16.906l1.621.731-1.467,1.006A11.921,11.921,0,0,1,14,24ZM14,2A10.011,10.011,0,0,0,4,12c-.155,7.117,7.763,12.2,14.155,9.082a11.544,11.544,0,0,1-.876-18.521A9.745,9.745,0,0,0,14,2Z"/></svg>`;
  modeToggle.innerHTML = daynightSVG;
  document.body.classList.toggle("darkModeToggled");
};
```

Comment: you can just toggle `display` css property of `svg` element

Comment: unfortunately, I can't since I'm changing the actual svg, my explanation is only for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an event listener on the button.

```
var daynightSVG = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" height="512"><path d="M24,13V11H18.928a6.927,6.927,0,0,0-.438-1.621l4.392-2.557L21.876,5.094,17.482,7.652a7.077,7.077,0,0,0-1.142-1.14l2.55-4.385L17.162,1.121l-2.55,4.385A6.91,6.91,0,0,0,13,5.072V0H11V5.072A6.908,6.908,0,0,0,9.4,5.5L6.854,1.121,5.126,2.127,7.671,6.5A7.046,7.046,0,0,0,6.524,7.646L2.14,5.094,1.134,6.822,5.513,9.371A6.9,6.9,0,0,0,5.072,11H0v2H5.072a6.948,6.948,0,0,0,.438,1.622L1.141,17.165l1.006,1.729,4.372-2.546a7.028,7.028,0,0,0,1.13,1.131L5.1,21.865l1.729,1.006,2.548-4.382A6.912,6.912,0,0,0,11,18.928V24h2V18.928a6.918,6.918,0,0,0,1.638-.445l2.552,4.388,1.728-1.006L16.362,17.47a7.06,7.06,0,0,0,1.125-1.128l4.383,2.552,1-1.729-4.382-2.551A6.928,6.928,0,0,0,18.928,13Zm-7-1c-.21,6.608-9.791,6.606-10,0C7.21,5.392,16.791,5.394,17,12Z"/></svg>`;
var modeToggle = document.getElementById("modeToggle");
modeToggle.innerHTML = daynightSVG;
var isDisplayDayNight=false

/*modeToggle.onclick = () => {
  modeToggle.innerHTML = daynightSVG;
  document.body.classList.toggle("darkModeToggled");
};*/

modeToggle.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    isDisplayDayNight=!isDisplayDayNight
    if(isDisplayDayNight){
        //in this if block you can control the display in any way JS  or CSS
        document.body.classList.toggle("darkModeToggled");
    }

})
```